# Having CORS issues with SAML2 with [itfoxtec-identity-saml2] .NET library from a fetch request

Tags: cors, fetch, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

My backend is pretty much a vanilla implementation of the IFoxTec-Identity-Saml2 libraries. When I hit it directly it properly redirects to azure ad, authenticates with whatever required interaction, and then back to my backend where it does the proper login on our servers.

Attempting to do this from a fetch request in chrome is failing with a CORS error, and it isn't redirecting to login.microsoftonline.com at all. I know I'm doing something simple wrong most likely:

My frontend:

```
  doSamlRedirect =() => {
    // this url properly redirects to login.microsoftonline.com when hit directly in a browser
    // authenticates, and redirects properly to my backend again and logs the user in in our database but fails with a cors error with this fetch
    const url = 'https://suite.mytestserver.us/auth/api/sso/login?tenant_name=fresh&client_id=client&grant_type=sso&user_type=user';
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include', // Include cookies for cross-origin requests
    })
      .then(response => {
        // The browser should follow the redirection automatically
        // No need to handle CORS explicitly in this case supposedly?
      })
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
  };
```

My simple backend relevant code using itfoxtec-identity-saml2:

controller:

```
        [Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromQuery] SamlLoginInfo info)
        {
            return externalAuthenticationService.RedirectToLogin(info);
        }
```

service:

```
        public IActionResult RedirectToLogin(LoginInfo loginInfo)
        {
            var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
            
            // RelayStateQuery stores stuff we want to round-trip to the provider
            var roundTripInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { Constants.TenantName, (loginInfo as SamlLoginInfo).TenantName }
            };

            binding.SetRelayStateQuery(roundTripInfo);
            config.SigningCertificate = null;
            var saml2Request = new Saml2AuthnRequest(config);
            return binding.Bind(saml2Request).ToActionResult();
            // this is returning a 302 with a redirect that the controller is sending to the browser
        }
```

I understand that my server after the fact will need to redirect the browser again to my own frontend with whatever token information is necessary, but I can't get it to display the login.microsoftonline.com login right now.

Edit:  I couldn't fix my cors issues with my fetch, I couldn't get my .NET startup cors bindings to properly send access-control-headers, instead I changed my frontend to just do a simple window.location.href which solved the problem.

Comment: Not sure why you would hit the login endpoint actively from the browser. SAML2 login endpoints are passive, you need to redirect rather than fetch. fetch probably redirects but it does so internally, you don't *see* the internal redirection in your browser (and you are not supposed to).

Comment: I'm hitting my own server's auth which does all the saml work to build up the redirect url to login.microsoftonline.com and sends back a redirect with all the proper stuff.

The problem was fixed by changing my fetch to a plain window.location.href and voila all is working fine, including the final redirect to my backend with AD user information, my backend grabs that, logs the user in with our own authentication schema, and then redirect the browser again to our single page application with our own auth JWT and session and the user is in.

Not sure if that clarifies for you @WiktorZychla

Comment: That my question was about, why fetch instead of redirect. Good you made same conclusion. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be eliminated by using a browser redirect method from the client, where the entier entire page is redirected.

Something like

```
window.location.href='https://...';
```

or

```
window.location.replace('https://...');
```